# Squeeze theorem and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I've been going over old calculus books to refresh my memory and have mainly been focusing on proofs. One of the things I found interesting was the squeeze theorem, even though since basic calculus i haven't used it much if at all. One of the proofs I know it is used for is the limit as x approaches 0 for $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. Bascially the proof consists of making 3 different area formulas in a sector of the unit circle. The areas of the triangles with height $\sin x$ and  $\tan x$ to "squeeze" the area of the sector with angle $x$. I understand and know the proof, my question is more about the theory behind the proof. The thing I don't understand about the proof is how someone went from trying to find the limit of $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ as it approaches zero, to using the squeeze theorem in the unit circle. Also why exactly is the Squeeze theorem used instead of some other method?

(On a side note is there any time that the Squeeze theorem is useful for finding limits in upper level math courses or physics courses?)

Edited to hopefully make it more understandable.

Comment: I think you are referring to a particular limit here where $x$ goes to zero? The "squeeze" is here that the term $\frac{sinx}{x}$ is "caught" between 1 and 1 and hence it goes to 1. Proofs of this feat are widely available on the internet.

Comment: For example, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/169852